# Compiler-definitions for Delphi 10.3 Rio?

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

Can anyone translate these compiler-definitions for **Delphi 10.3 Rio**? Thank you in advance.

```
{$IFDEF VER320}  //Embarcadero Delphi 10.2 Tokyo (25 - Godzilla) - 2017
  {$DEFINE D4PLUS}
  {$DEFINE D5PLUS}
  {$DEFINE D6PLUS}
  {$DEFINE D7PLUS}
  {$DEFINE BDS3PLUS}{$DEFINE D2005PLUS}
  {$DEFINE BDS4PLUS}{$DEFINE D2006PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD5PLUS}{$DEFINE D2007PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD6PLUS}{$DEFINE D2009PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD7PLUS}{$DEFINE D2010PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD8PLUS}{$DEFINE DXEPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD9PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE2PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD10PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE3PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD11PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE4PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD12PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE5PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD14PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE6PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD15PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE7PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD16PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE8PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD17PLUS}{$DEFINE DSEATTLEPLUS}{$DEFINE DXSPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD18PLUS}{$DEFINE DBERLINPLUS}{$DEFINE DXBPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD19PLUS}{$DEFINE DTOKYOPLUS}{$DEFINE DXTPLUS}
  {$DEFINE THEMESUPPORT}
  {$DEFINE NATIVEINT}
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{$IFDEF VER330}  //Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 Rio (26 - ?) - 2018
  {$DEFINE D4PLUS}
  {$DEFINE D5PLUS}
  {$DEFINE D6PLUS}
  {$DEFINE D7PLUS}
  {$DEFINE BDS3PLUS}{$DEFINE D2005PLUS}
  {$DEFINE BDS4PLUS}{$DEFINE D2006PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD5PLUS}{$DEFINE D2007PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD6PLUS}{$DEFINE D2009PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD7PLUS}{$DEFINE D2010PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD8PLUS}{$DEFINE DXEPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD9PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE2PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD10PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE3PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD11PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE4PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD12PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE5PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD14PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE6PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD15PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE7PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD16PLUS}{$DEFINE DXE8PLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD17PLUS}{$DEFINE DSEATTLEPLUS}{$DEFINE DXSPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD18PLUS}{$DEFINE DBERLINPLUS}{$DEFINE DXBPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD19PLUS}{$DEFINE DTOKYOPLUS}{$DEFINE DXTPLUS}
  {$DEFINE RAD20PLUS}{$DEFINE DRIOPLUS}{$DEFINE DXRPLUS}
  {$DEFINE THEMESUPPORT}
  {$DEFINE NATIVEINT}
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: You need to add the defines for Rio, and you need to keep the `VER320` `IFDEF`